# .htaccess и файл со списком ip адресов

Tags: .htaccess

Можно ли в .htaccess вместо перечисления каждого ip адреса, указать путь до файла .txt (либо какой другой) в котором будут перечислены ip адреса спам-ботов, для их блокировки? Нужно это для того, чтобы спам-ловушка автоматом пополняла этот файл ip адресами спамерщиков, а .htaccess уже их блокировал. Возможно это? Подскажите как правильно сделать запись в .htaccess

Comment: Насколько помню, никаких штатных инклюдов у htaccsess нет. И если у вас есть некая «спам-ловушка», то пусть она сразу пополняет, например, правила iptables, чтобы апач даже не занимался такими проверками.

Answer (score 0):

Для .htaccess такое не предусмотрено.
Используйте fail2ban, он может банить ip на лету по заданным правилам, в том числе по данным из логов.